# Python: Can strftime() function deal with Quarter date transform?

Tags: python, date, datetime, strptime

I need to deal with a lot of date format transformations in Python. The input date format may like `"2018/07/07"` in type string. It is easy to use datetime.() function to transform it to `'2018-07-07T00:00:00'`. However, some special date formats may concern me a lot like `"2018Q1"`, which meant the first quarter of year 2018.

I found there is nothing can use to describe the quarter in strftime function.
I tried:

```
import time, datetime
time_original = "2018Q1"
time_format = datetime.datetime.strptime(time_original,"%YQ%m")
time_format = time_format.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
print(time_format)

output:
'2018-01-01T00:00:00'
```

What I really want is `'2018-03-01T00:00:00'` or `'2018-03-31T00:00:00'` to let me know, ok it's Quarter date.

Further concern:
Due to some date format may like `'18/07'`,using the function can only shows the first day of month `'2018-07-01T00:00:00'`but not last day of the month. I wanna normalize the data all in last day of month if there is no "day" from input date.

Comment: I would take a look at [pandas.Period.strftime()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Period.strftime.html). It looks like it supports quarters with `%q`.

Comment: @HernánAlarcón It's a nice advise, however, the input is actually from a nested json file, once I normalized all the date , I need return the result back to json. I am afraid of if it would be too complex and time-consuming , first transform to pd, then figure it out and process, finally return back to dict format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer to question: no, not to my knowledge. To provide an alternative: you could use `pandas.to_datetime` to automatically parse the quarter, e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
print(pd.to_datetime("2018Q1").isoformat())
# 2018-01-01T00:00:00
```

...or write your own parser, e.g.

```
from datetime import datetime

def year_quarter_to_ymd(s):
    parts = s.upper().split('Q')
    dt = datetime(int(parts[0]), int(parts[1])*3-2, 1)
    return dt.isoformat()

tstrings = ["2018Q1","2018Q2","2018Q3","2018Q4"]

for t in tstrings:
    print(year_quarter_to_ymd(t))
    
# 2018-01-01T00:00:00
# 2018-04-01T00:00:00
# 2018-07-01T00:00:00
# 2018-10-01T00:00:00
```

While less convenient, the custom function runs faster on my machine:

```
%timeit pd.to_datetime("2018Q1").isoformat()
69.1 µs ± 289 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit year_quarter_to_ymd("2018Q1")
1.32 µs ± 3.01 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

That really works! Thanks so much @MrFuppes and based on his answer, I tried use `calendar` function to find out the last day automatically. Also it works! Update the result here:

```
from datetime import datetime
import calendar

def year_quarter_to_ymd(s):
    parts = s.upper().split('Q')
    end = calendar.monthrange(int(parts[0]), int(parts[1])*3)[1]
    dt = datetime(int(parts[0]), int(parts[1])*3, end)
    return dt.isoformat()

print(year_quarter_to_ymd("2019Q1"))

#2019-03-31T00:00:00
```